# Is a subgroup a right coset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem posted below. However, I'm already stuck at question i) because I don't really understand what they're asking. What do they mean by showing show that H is a right coset? I have no information about H other than it is a subgroup of G. That doesn't necessarily make it to a right coset? Or is there a mistake in the question?

[image]

Comment: The question is somewhat poorly worded.  It's nonsensical to ask whether something is a coset without the context of it being a coset of some subgroup.  In this case, the question is expecting you to infer that since there are no other subgroups mentioned, that "is a right coset" means "is a right coset of $H$ (itself)".

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. Also, please share the source of the text.

Comment: It says $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, @ErickWong.

Comment: @Shaun When did I say that $H$ is not a subgroup?

Comment: I misread your comment, @ErickWong. I'm sorry.

Comment: Hint for (ii): show that $g'\in gH \Longrightarrow Hg'^{-1}=Hg^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking you to show that there exists a $g\in G$ such that

$$H=Hg.$$

Then it asks you to show that, for any $a,b\in G$, if $Ha\neq Hb$, then

$$Ha\cap Hb=\varnothing.$$

These are standard exercises that have been covered countless times here.

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of personal taste, but the very name of "\emptyset" makes this "$\emptyset$" seemingly more appropriate than "$\varnothing$".

Comment: I prefer $\varnothing$, @fitzcarraldo. I don't know why.

Comment: Fair enough, @Shaun.